# How do I change custom profile fields in with Jira Rest Api?

Tags: php, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin

We use a [plugin](http://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1212508/user-profiles-for-jira) for Jira that allows you to add custom fields on the user profiles. Is there a way to add and change those custom fields with the API? The custom fields are stored in the personal section of the users page (if that makes any differnce).

This is the code that we use to get the JSON to be able to read the profiles. Although it does not show us the custom fields added with said plugin.

```
$username = 'test';
$password = 'test123';
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,'http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/user?username=test');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
$query = curl_exec($curl_handle);
$wantedString = json_decode($query);
print_r($wantedString->name);
$wantedString->name = 'test1';
print_r($wantedString);
```

[image]

Comment: what is the plugin name?

Comment: If the plugin's documentation said so then you can add else you cannot add/remove fields from the third party plugin. Ask the plugin developer (company) if there's any REST api to achieve this and the answer of this question will answer your question too.